# Can I have more than 2 outs on a Multi-Output Device

Tags: audio

I'm using a loopback audio device called BlackHole 16ch which has 16 ins and 16 outs and I have a USB Audio Interface with 2 ins and 4 outs. Here are the devices:

[image: UMC204HD 192k]

[image: Blackhole 16ch]

I want to create a Multi-Output device with my Audio Interface as the master device and the BlackHole device as a mirrored device, but when I create it, it is created with only 0 ins and 2 outs:

[image: Multi-Output Device]

I want to use the Blackhole device to route audio into OBS while being able to monitor Ableton Live Cue Out in my headphones from my USB device's outputs 3 and 4

It seems that Multi-Output devices are limited to a single stereo pair though, which is frustrating. Is there a good workaround?

I have tried Rogue Amoeba's Loopback Audio that is flexible enough to route in the way I want, but introduces quite noticeable latency to my Headphone monitors.

screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyUys.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround to this limitation of Multi-Output devices is to use an Aggregate device in the following way:

1. Create an Aggregate device with the USB Interface as the master:

[image: Aggregate Device Audio Settings]

note that outputs 1-4 and inputs 1-2 are the USB Interface and outputs 5-20 and inputs 3-18 are the Blackhole 16ch loopback device

2. Set Live's Audio Device to the Aggregate Device:

[image: Live Audio Settings]

3. Configure and label the first 3 stereo pair outputs in Ableton Live:

[image: Live Output config]

4. Configure and label the inputs in Ableton Live:

[image: Live Input config]

5. Set the Cue Out to 3/4 Headphones, and the Master Out to 5/6 Loopback:

[image: Master Audio outputs]

6. Click the Solo/Cue toggle in the master channel to reveal Cue buttons for each track

[image: Solo/Cue toggle]

7. Create a new audio track, mute it, set Audio To "Sends Only", set Monitor to "In", set Audio From to "Ext. In", "3/4 Loopback", click the little headphone button on the audio track you just set up.

[image: Loopback monitoring track]

Now we have Master being sent to Blackhole 16ch loopback device, which we can route to our other applications like OBS, while monitoring it in Live, and having our click track and other Cue Out being monitored.